# Mudando o nome das linhas de uma lista no R usando lapply a partir de uma variável lista

Tags: r, lapply

Tenho uma lista chamada dataLista e gostaria que o nome das linhas fossem iguais a uma variável chamada CNPJ que está dentro dessa lista.
Para isso, primeiro apliquei:

```
dadosLista<-lapply(dadosLista, "rownames<-", dadosLista$CNPJ)
```

Porém, dadosLista$CNPJ é considerada uma variável vazia. Dessa forma, criei a lista CNPJ:

```
CNPJ<-lapply(dadosLista, `[`, 3)
```

E em seguida:

```
dadosLista<-lapply(dadosLista, "rownames<-", CNPJ)
```

Apareceu o erro:

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
'row.names' com comprimento inválido
```

Deve ser algum problema que estou tendo com o entendimento de lapply.

Comment: Um `dput(dadosLista)` poderia ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi esse problema utilizando um comando for da seguinte maneira:

```
for (i in 1:340){
rownames(dadosLista[[i]])<-dadosLista[[i]][,c(3)]
}
```

Em que a coluna 3 representam os valores desejados para os nomes das linhas.